# How to print the alphabet followed by a carriage return and linfeed?

Tags: assembly, while-loop, x86, x86-16, dosbox

Printing a-z.
        mov DL, 'A' ;
        cmp DL, 'Z' ;
        jge Next ; 
        add DL, 01H ; adds one to DL
        jmp addPrint ;

Comment: carriage return CR and linefeed LF are ASCII characters like 'A' ... See ASCII table.

Comment: It seems you are being too ambitious. First try writing a program that simply prints out 'A'.

Answer (score 1):

1. At first, in your program there is no printing at all. Only loop that cycles from "A" to "Y" (off-by-one mistake) and then goes to Next.
2. In your case, you don't need `.data` and `.bss` sections. `.data` should contain the initialized data needed by your program (strings, tables, etc.) and `.bss` the not initialized data. (BTW, what is the assembler? The therm "section" is usually used in protected mode programming, not DOS. Usually it is called "segment".)
3. If you are trying to create DOS .com file (org 100h) you can't use multiply segments. So, you must have only one segment and put all the code and data there.

Comment: 1. Ok thanks for clearing that up. 2. I was thinking that with the .data and .bss sections but wasn't completely sure. 3. I'm creating a .asm file. Sorry if it was unclear, I'm using DOSBOX and then using nasmide inside of it.

Comment: @throwawayjava - please, add to the question a tag about the assembler used. It is very important because different assemblers have different syntax.

Comment: Looks like Nasm syntax... `section` == `segment`, so that's okay. You want the initial `mov dl, 'A'` outside your loop - you'll never exit the loop if you reset it to 'A' every time. You need to put a function number in `ah` before the `int 21h` - `2` to print `dl` and `4Ch` to exit.

Comment: @FrankKotler Ok, thanks for the advice and the infinite loop resolution!